# If and how to use the has_and_belongs_to_many association in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord, model-associations

Trying to create a domain in which a user can create list of coffees and blends. A blend has many coffees and a coffee has many blends. This is what I have so far:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roasts
  has_many :blends, :through => :roasts

class Roast < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  # TODO: associate roasts with blends

class Blend < ActiveRecord::Base
  # TODO: associate blends with roasts
```

How do I establish this relationship? Will I need a join table of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

Hi! I think that you can define the association like below code block.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blend_and_roasts
  has_many :blends, through: :blend_and_roasts
  has_many :roasts, through: :blend_and_roasts

class Roast < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blend_and_roasts
  has_many :blends, through: :blend_and_roasts

class Blend < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blend_and_roasts
  has_many :roasts, through: :blend_and_roasts
```

Happy coding!

Comment: @AlexSegers Could you tell me how db schema is defined?

Comment: @AlexSegers I edited the answer so please check what you want.
p.s adding `inverse_of` option makes app fast but I didn't do that because I want to make the answer more clear